# How xpath works for tags in tags

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find out the xpath for first name of the facebook page and I have ended it with the following xpath: "`**//div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[@class='inputtext _58mg _5dba _2ph-']**`" which is correct. My question is that, there are total 9 div tags on the page but I got it with the fourth div, I am not getting the reason how it's finding it in fourth div? 
Page is **Facebook home Page** and element to find with xpath is Fist name input box
Please help me to understand how it's finding the element using above xpath

I know there are other ways to find xpath but I want to know the reason how it's finding it
I hope I am providing the complete information for the asked question if not let me know

Answer (score 0):

Well it's because your `xpath` starts with a `//`. In literal english, it says find a `DIV` whose child is a `DIV` whose child is a `DIV` whose child is a `DIV` whose child is your `INPUT`. In your case, it does find a `DIV` which has `INPUT` as described by your `xpath`.

If you replace that `//` to single `/`, it will find the first `DIV` and then will try finding your input. Which it won't be able to find since .. like you said there are 9 `DIV`s.

Hope that paints a picture. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped me to understand